# using javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, printing

What am I doing wrong with this code, I can't get it to print out the name of any of the teams. I want it to output the name of the first team or second team etc. But nothing works. Any help?

```
   var seeds = [
        { "id" : 1, "name" : "Team 1" }
        { "id" : 2, "name" : "Team 2" }
        { "id" : 3, "name" : "Team 3" }
        { "id" : 4, "name" : "Team 4" }
        { "id" : 5, "name" : "Team 5" }
        { "id" : 6, "name" : "Team 6" }
        { "id" : 7, "name" : "Team 7" }
        { "id" : 8, "name" : "Team 8" }
    ]
    document.write(seeds[0].name);
```

Comment: Are you aware that document.write can't be used once the document is loaded ? And your code can't compile : commas are missing.

Comment: You are missing a comma after each item: { id: 1, name: 'team 1' }, ...

Comment: Please check you show us code that compiles before posting. We'll have there a dozen identical answers just because you didn't look at the console.

Comment: @dystroy I had no compiling errors, I am using node.js and it compiled, it just didn't show anything where I wanted it to. Sorry

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot the commas:

```
var seeds = [
    { "id" : 1, "name" : "Team 1" },
    { "id" : 2, "name" : "Team 2" },
    { "id" : 3, "name" : "Team 3" },
    { "id" : 4, "name" : "Team 4" },
    { "id" : 5, "name" : "Team 5" },
    { "id" : 6, "name" : "Team 6" },
    { "id" : 7, "name" : "Team 7" },
    { "id" : 8, "name" : "Team 8" }
];
```

`seeds` is an `Array`, and you will have to seperate the element's with a comma, like this:

```
var s = [{},{},{},{}];
```

Notice that there isn't a comma after the last element.

Comment: Could you also tell me why this `{ "id" : 1, "name" : $('#team1').val() },` does not print anything? The javascript file is seperate to the html, but when I use the same idea inside the html it works, however I'm trying to define each of the team names using a series of textboxes.

Comment: That code is in a `.js` file you're embedding with a `<script>` tag?
Your code will probably be executed before the document has fully loaded, then. [Take a look at the `onload` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onload)

Comment: You are correct, it is running before the text has been entered. How would you run the script afterwards? My guess would be to include it at the bottom of the page but that's most likely wrong

Comment: @germainelol: that would be a option, or add a load event listener that executes the code: `window.addEventListener('load', yourFunctionHere)`

Comment: This would be on the html page of the .js file? I tried putting all of my .js file into a new function called load and doing an onload, but it didn't work

Answer (score 2):

Each object should have a comma between them

```
var seeds = [
    { "id" : 1, "name" : "Team 1" },
    { "id" : 2, "name" : "Team 2" },
    { "id" : 3, "name" : "Team 3" },
    { "id" : 4, "name" : "Team 4" },
    { "id" : 5, "name" : "Team 5" },
    { "id" : 6, "name" : "Team 6" },
    { "id" : 7, "name" : "Team 7" },
    { "id" : 8, "name" : "Team 8" }
]
document.write(seeds[0].name);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `,` in the Array

```
var seeds = [
    { "id" : 1, "name" : "Team 1" },
    { "id" : 2, "name" : "Team 2" },
    { "id" : 3, "name" : "Team 3" },
    { "id" : 4, "name" : "Team 4" },
    { "id" : 5, "name" : "Team 5" },
    { "id" : 6, "name" : "Team 6" },
    { "id" : 7, "name" : "Team 7" },
    { "id" : 8, "name" : "Team 8" }
]
document.write(seeds[0].name);
```

Answer (score 2):

Put commas between the elements:

```
var seeds = [
    { "id" : 1, "name" : "Team 1" },
    { "id" : 2, "name" : "Team 2" },
    { "id" : 3, "name" : "Team 3" },
    { "id" : 4, "name" : "Team 4" },
    { "id" : 5, "name" : "Team 5" },
    { "id" : 6, "name" : "Team 6" },
    { "id" : 7, "name" : "Team 7" },
    { "id" : 8, "name" : "Team 8" }
]
document.write(seeds[0].name);
```